# Define templatesParameters in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, html-webpack-plugin

As far as I know Create React App uses HTMLWebpackPlugin. Is it possible to define in CRA templates parameters to use them in index.html file (HTML template for my app). If so, how? Generally speaking I would like to define parameter/variable and use it in index.html to inject scripts conditionally:

```
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.templatesParameters.GA) { %>
  <script> ... some GA code ...</script>
<% } %>
```